# Getting a Single

Tags: templating, entries

It appears that getting a entry that is a single is more tricky that it should be.

This works,

```
craft.entries.section('footer').first()
```

This does not work,

```
craft.entries.section('footer').limit(1)
```

This does not work,

```
craft.entries.section('footer')
```

Does any one know of any documentation that lays out the usage of when to use limit, nothing, and first()? Seems very confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The first example you showed is the exact right way to do it.**

The second & third examples you showed will technically work, but return an array of entries. Your single would be the only entry inside that array.

In your second & third examples, you're dealing with an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel). You can append several methods to an ECM to generate results from it...

- `first()` - Returns an individual Entry (in this case your Single)
- `find()` - Returns an array of matching entries
- `ids()` - Returns an array of entry IDs
- `total()` - Returns a number (total matches)
- `last()` - Opposite of `first()`
- `nth()` - Returns an individual Entry

**Important to note...** If you don't specify one of these methods, then `find()` will be automatically applied when it's used as an array.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, and for providing additional context beyond the OP's question. If the 2nd & 3rd examples return an array, would `craft.entries.section('footer')[0]` work?

Comment: @NathanDHuening: Might want to post that as a separate question. Feel free to link back to this thread for reference.

Comment: In Craft CMS 4.x `first()` is not defined, you have to use `one()` instead.