# What other properties are in the "entry.image" object?

Tags: templating, entry, image

So this may be a stupid question, but I've sort of never wrapped my head around it. When fetching an image from an entry -- even if there's only one associated with the field -- you can't just do:

```
{% set image = entry.image %}
```

You have to say:

```
{% set image = entry.image.first() %}
```

Which implies that the returned data are an object or array, and that the actual desired image is the "first" item in it. My questions are:

1. Why is it structured this way?
2. Which other properties are in the `entry.image` apart from the actual resource itself? What would you use those for?

I realize this may be obvious to pro Craft developers, but I remember the first Craft site I ever built, I had a devil of a time trying to remember that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference a relationship field (ie: Entries field, Assets field, etc), you will automatically get an **ElementCriteriaModel** to represent the "value" of that field.

Since `entry.image` is giving you an ElementCriteriaModel, you need to specify exactly what you want that ECM to do. If you try to use the ECM without specifying `.first` (or `.last`, or `.total`), then by default it will *assume* you meant `.find`. Which is obviously not what you're trying to do in this case.

I highly recommend reading my answer on [this other thread...](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/16070/45) It's not quite a duplicate of your question, but it covers a lot of the same ground.

Comment: Ah OK, that's making more sense, and thank you for the link to your other answer. So when creating fields for a section, is every 'asset' field a 'relationship' field? I know as a field 'entries' would be, but I didn't realize the same would be true for images/assets. Does that then imply the other fields, like 'plain text' and 'light switch' are **not** relationships? Follow-up Q: Of all the possible fields to associate with a section, which are which? Thank you!

Comment: Relationship fields are any fields based on _elements_... I'd recommend reading up on [Element Types](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#creating-an-elementCriteriaModel), as they're a pretty crucial part of the Craft ecosystem.